# C++/CLI FIFO - List vs. Array for serialPort reading

Tags: c++-cli, serial-port, buffer, fifo

I have quite silly basic question. But i think that it could be very useful for many other junior programmers.

I am communicating quite fast(12Mb/s) via serialPort (receiving) and I want to make a FIFO buffer for String^s, which I will extract from incoming messages(start bytes - message with details - stop bytes). What would you recommend me?

A) Should I use solid buffer based on Array class?

B) Should I use dynamic buffer based on List class?

Thank you very much.

PS: I also have to mention, that data collection to this array runs in one thread. Second thread decode string from this buffer and third thread manages both threads.

Comment: Ok. So far I am browsing List class, it looks that List is better, but I am not sure about speed of this Class.

Comment: A `Queue<String^>^` is appropriate here.  Don't forget to lock to make it thread-safe.  ConcurrentQueue if you target .NET 4.

Comment: That seems like answer. So if you want to answer it, make it as answer or I answer it myself tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

as Hans has written, the best solution of my problem is **class Queue**, with all hardness connected with it.